# is there difference between Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer.emailAddress and Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When creating a new meeting/appointment on outlook , is there difference between

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer => emailAddress
```

and

```
Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be. If a user is creating a meeting on behalf of someone else.

Say an administrative assistant (`a@consoto.com`) is creating a meeting on behalf of their boss (`b@consoto.com`.) The organizer will be `b@consoto.com`, but the mailbox emailAddress would be `a@consoto.com`, as `a` is the logged in user. To get the email address of the shared calendar, use the [Shared Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sharedproperties?view=outlook-js-preview) object.